# How do you start the app with the profiler in "trace java methods" mode?

Tags: android-studio, profiling, android-studio-3.3, android-profiler

We are ready to optimise app startup time.

The ultimate goal is to, quote

> cold start into fragment X as quickly as the calculator is starting up

I do have a few ideas on what we could tweak to try and speed up loading, but I'd like to verify them before bothering to try them out.

So I open the profiler view and hit the app launch configuration.

[image: profiler without call chart]

Ok ... no trace.

Unfortunately, I cannot hit the `record` button until *after* the app has loaded. Which doesn't do me any good because I'm trying to get a profile of the startup.

Any way I can launch with the record feature already active?

**UPDATE**

Yes, you can if you edit the run configuration, buuuut that's not giving you any relevant information because even then, it only starts recording the information AFTER the startup.

[image]

Comment: On Android Studio Electric Eel 2022.1.1 Patch 1, editing run config with profiling method trace (not-legacy) works fine now

Answer (score 9):

To enable advanced profiling, follow these steps:

- Select Run > Edit Configurations.
- Select your app module in the left pane.
- Click the Profiling tab, and then check Enable advanced profiling for older devices.
- Select Run > Profiler.

This will start the app and start recording immediately, you only need to hit stop recording once you want.