# Find who is making call to gms.persistent

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging, perfetto

I am working on a big java + kotlin codebase - it has services, activities, etc - which ultimately compiles to an Android apk. I am trying to improve performance of this app. I found that in Perfetto, it is showing a huge 1.4s binder transaction , relating to com.google.android.gms.persistent .

[image]

*(I removed process names)*

I want to know from where in the code is this call going to gms.persistent , but from Perfetto I am not able to find that out. Also, I was trying to figure which google api calls in general lead to such calls, but from documentation I was not able to find that out. Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use app_profiler in Android Studio to collect call samples, which may help find out who called the binding operation.

[How do you start the app with the profiler in "trace java methods" mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55188548/how-do-you-start-the-app-with-the-profiler-in-trace-java-methods-mode)